# Why the JPA EntityManager isn't thread-safe by definition?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jpa, orm

As I know, it is practically a pool, a two-way read & write cache of the persistent JPA entities.

I think, this is the typical situation of a class which should be really thread-safe, parallel and reentrant.

But I read consequently on the net, that it is not the situation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668378/how-to-get-entitymanager-programmatically-in-spring) I even read, that this is the situation *by* *definition*.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone can read the JPA spec, section 7.2

> An entity manager must not be shared among multiple concurrently
>   executing threads, as the entity manager and persistence context are
>   not required to be threadsafe. Entity managers must only be accessed
>   in a single-threaded manner.

An `EntityManager` is a quick to create and dispose object, and follows from the most common use-case of request-response, where you create an `EntityManager` at the start of the request, and close it at the end. It is no "pool" of objects, while it does maintain a cache of objects it has encountered in its lifetime. An EntityManagerFactory is thread-safe.

PS The question is not suited to Stackoverflow, as the Help section above would tell you. It is not "some problem you have had", and is likely to "create discussion".