# Getting the EntityManager created by OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter programmatically

Tags: spring, jpa, entity, servlet-filters, interceptor

*([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668378/how-to-get-entitymanager-programmatically-in-spring) is satisfied by an annotation & aop - based solution, which is exactly the opposite as my case. Please don't sign that as duplicate.)*

I use the named Servlet filter to get a different, thread-local EntityManager for every request.

I want to get the EntityManager which belongs to the actual Servlet Request (thread).

I want a simple procedural solution. Annotating some of my classes with spring aop things doesn't play, this were exactly which I want to avoid.

---

P.s. digging a little bit into the [spring source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java), I could find in `spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java` the following code, which creates and EntityManager and registers it in the actual Request:

```
EntityManager em = createEntityManager(emf);
EntityManagerHolder emHolder = new EntityManagerHolder(em);
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(emf, emHolder);

AsyncRequestInterceptor interceptor = new AsyncRequestInterceptor(emf, emHolder);
asyncManager.registerCallableInterceptor(key, interceptor);
asyncManager.registerDeferredResultInterceptor(key, interceptor);
```

As I can see, this code somehow registers the newly created EntityManager into the actual thread-local data. The question were a "beautiful" way to get this data out by a clear procedural solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything Spring related or AOP related in your classes that want an `EntityManager`. Just put a field of the type `EntityManager` and put the default `@PersistenceContext` (from JPA) on it and the right `EntityManager` will be injected. Nothing AOP related.

```
public class MyDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

}
```

If you also have the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` that will create an `EntityManager` and bind it to the current executing thread. This will then be injected into that field (well actually it is a proxy that delegates the call).

Assuming that you have `<context:annotation-config />` or `<context:component-scan />`  in your configuration the `@PersistenceContext` should work. When using Java based config this is enabled by default.

Comment: I have, and it doesn't work, EntityManager remained null, independent what I did. Finally I removed every annotations (even the @Transactional ones) and now I am on the way to do everything procedurally. It was a major refactoring of the project. And it will work. I know.

Comment: I doubt you have else it would have worked, you haven't posted your config so what the actual problem is (I suspect misconfiguration). So if you still need help, add your configuration (xml and possible web.xml).

Comment: I am sorry, already I see that your answer is correct and okay. Unfortunately, I used a tragical quality Spring AOP thingy and I fighted with it to make it working correctly, this was the real cause of my troubles.